# nagios creating custom alert for jenkins

Tags: linux, nagios

Hi I have a problem when deploying with jenkins. the problem is that when the deploy is being made my load average goes up so the alert triggers, but I want to create  a rule or I want a way to disable load average notifications when jenkins process is up.

does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to disable notification for a host automatically I usually use `curl`:

```
curl -s -d "cmd_typ=${cmd}&cmd_mod=2&host=${host}&ahas=on&btnSubmit=Commit" $url
```

where:

"$cmd" can be "enable" or "disable"

"$url" is https://user:password@host:port/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi

"$host" your hostname

PS. Mind you that it will disable notifications for all services in that host.

Comment: thanks for your comment, do you know a way to disable just the load average notification?

Comment: @DiegoVelez, you can play with the "tamper data" plugin in firefox to see how the post variables look like when you disable that service.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/58966/nagios-disable-notifications-from-command-line-on-windows-linux

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Nagios to monitoring Jenkins jobs. When the jobs started in the Jenkins, trigger a script to disable notifications on Nagios server for the specified application server or whatever you want.

Edit:
I have not done this before. I'm trying to implement Jenkins in my work now, the next step will be the Nagios configuration for Jenkins server monitoring.

One ideia is the use of this plugin:
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/Jenkins-Plugin/details

The option of this plugin that concerns us is the *buildDurationThresholdMilliseconds: It will alert if the last build took longer than this number of milliseconds to complete*

Now, the trick is make a trigger from this alert to a command or script that will disable the load average alert on nagios. You can use the script seeing in the Tiago comment's

Comment: Yea I was thinking on that but how can I do that? can this script be helpful? http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/check_jenkins/details